# Xamarin.android + auth0 authentification error: net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, auth0

I want to login at my xamarin.android application via auth0. I found this tutorial that describes it so nice.

I just use xamarin.android instead "pure" android app on c#.

But I have this error:
 [image]

As you see, I have the valid responce from auth0 with `callback?code={code}`
but it seems there are some problem with the intent activation method. (it can't parse responce in right scheme. Perhaps, it assume it's url adress and make just redirect call via browser).

There is my code of MainActivity:

```
usings ***

namespace myApp.intake.Mobile.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App", 
        Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme", 
        MainLauncher = true,
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    [IntentFilter(
        new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        DataScheme = "myApp.intake.mobile",
        DataHost = "myApp-dev.auth0.com",
        DataPathPrefix = "/android/myApp.intake.mobile/callback")]
    public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
            {
                Domain = "myApp-dev.auth0.com",
                ClientId = "************", //real clientId
                Activity = this
            });

            Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            this.PerformAuth0Login();
        }

        protected override async void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            // I have to get redirected here but it just throw the mentioned error!!!!!!
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);

            var loginResult = await client.ProcessResponseAsync(intent.DataString, authorizeState);

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (loginResult.IsError)
            {
                // logic to handle the error
            }
            // next business logic
        }

        #region Private Logic

        private async void PerformAuth0Login()
        {
            // Prepare for the login
            authorizeState = await client.PrepareLoginAsync();

            // Send the user off to the authorization endpoint
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(authorizeState.StartUrl);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
            StartActivity(intent); //I think problem here..
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Fields

        private Auth0Client client;
        private AuthorizeState authorizeState;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want from our side

Comment: @G.hakim just help to resolve this problem with error (net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME). Redirect application with code to OnNewIntent method for finishing the authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just solved it.

I forgot to point out that Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable categories at IntentFilter:

```
[Activity(...)]
[IntentFilter(
        new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataScheme = "myApp.intake.mobile",
        DataHost = "myApp-dev.auth0.com",
        DataPathPrefix = "/android/myApp.intake.mobile/callback")]
    public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{...}
```

As I understood this attribute must be compiled into AndroidManifest.xml file into something like this:

```
  <activity
    android:name="com.spotify.sdk.demo.DemoActivity"
    android:label="IntakeMobile"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data
         android:host="callback"
         android:scheme="testschema"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

I hope it will save some time for someone.